# Add text color toggle to show/hide a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a working toggle function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".hidecontrol").click(function(){
      $(".hide").toggle(300)
    });
});
```

I want to add a text colour change to a new class ".nohide" that also toggles. I have been trying

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hidecontrol").click(function(){
    $(".hide").toggle(300),
       $(".hidecontrol").css('color', 'red')
   });
 });
```

but this is 'permanent' after the first click, and doesn't toggle back. Is there a way to add a CSS color change to a .toggle() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(".hidecontrol").toggleClass('redcolor')
your css
.redcolor {color:red}

Comment: Thanks. This code starts the class'redcolor' as red rather than it's original colour for some reason, but I can just switch the colours in the CSS. Thanks again!